# What part of Windows 10 SDK do I need to install to get MakeAppx.exe?

Tags: winapi, uwp, windows-installer, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to follow [Microsoft's "Project Centennial" directions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to convert MSI installer for my app to UWP, and I'm getting this error that `MakeAppx.exe` isn't found:

[image]

This Windows 10 is not my development machine. So I went out to download Windows 10 SDK but at this point I'm curious what "part" of SDK is `MakeAppx.exe` located in? Or do I really need to download and install 2.3 GB for that?

[image]

Comment: The message is telling you you need to install *the complete Windows 10 SDK*, which presumably means that you're going to need more of it than MakeAppx.exe before you're done.

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, I saw that. IMO it's just a generic error message. But oh well, I guess I'll have to download and install 2.3 GB of stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the last option - which says "Windows Software Development Kit" includes MakeAppx.exe. You don't need the other things from the SDK to convert.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, any luck with that `Project Centennial`? I converted my Win32 app to UWP and submitted it, and then nothing... what's supposed to happen to it then?

Comment: Submitted to where? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge?

Comment: Yes, that's the page. Although it looked different at the time. Not all fields were present. Do I need to resubmit?

Comment: If you have already used that form to submit your interest/app, then please work with the Microsoft representative who was working with you to know more. If you haven't heard back, please try to resubmit your request using the form on the site.

Comment: I've submitted it again. Although I doubt that anyone will respond. It's been almost a month since my first submission.

Comment: If you still haven't heard back can you provide the minimum details you provided in the form such as the app name/ URL field?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it. I did get an automated reply that they were not able to process my submission. The reason -- `A valid app URL is required to validate the app or game. This can be a link to your website or current distribution platform (such as Steam or Download.com).` I submitted a URL to a ZIP'ed version of the app, with the `.appx` file and a `readme.txt` with explanation. It was hosted on my web site. Should I submit it differently?

Comment: The message is saying that during the form submission process, it wants the URL to your existing desktop app/game which you want to convert and publish to the Store. It is not asking for the URL of the converted APPX (which looks like what you provided).

Comment: Oh, I see. I did it wrong again. Thanks for clearing it out. Btw, can you update your contact info in the SO profile? I'll DM or email you the details that you asked before. I can't post them here.

Comment: OK, just sent you an email.

Answer (score 13):

Update for 10.0.16299.91 - Released November 2017:

The options have changed.  You only need to install "Windows App Certification Kit."

The location of `makeappx.exe` is now `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit`

Comment: if i have my appx file in folder C:\user\store\source and makeappx.exe in ..x86\windows kits\ where to execute the makeappx file

Comment: Checking it doesn't seem to install anything.